# Converting Text to Variable/Matrix Objects in R to shorten code

Tags: r, string, matrix

I was wondering if there was a way for me to change variable names in a loop or a function etc. rather than having to write many lines of code over and over again.

For example, I have included some code below:

```
AAA111 <- Matrixsubset[Matrixsubset[,"Buyer.ID"]=="111" | Matrixsubset[,"Seller.ID"]=="111"]
AAA111$STOCKS <- stock.function(111, AAA111)
AAA111$STOCKS.Value <- AAA111$STOCKS * AAA111$Price

bbb222 <- Matrixsubset[Matrixsubset[,"Buyer.ID"]=="222" | Matrixsubset[,"Seller.ID"]=="222"]
bbb222$STOCKS <- stock.function(222, bbb222)
bbb222$STOCKS.Value <- bbb222$STOCKS * bbb222$Price

ccc333 <- Matrixsubset[Matrixsubset[,"Buyer.ID"]=="333" | Matrixsubset[,"Seller.ID"]=="333"]
ccc333$STOCKS <- stock.function(333, ccc333)
ccc333$STOCKS.Value <- ccc333$STOCKS * ccc333$Price
```

(The objects `AAA111`, `bbb222` etc. are `xts` objects which is why new columns can be added to them using the `$` operator)

As you can see, the code is very repetitive. AAA111 is a matrix, while bbb222 is another matrix, and ccc333 is yet another matrix, and there are several other matrices which follow this identical format so my code looks very very cluttered and messy.

Basically, I was wondering if there was a more convenient and nicer way of doing this rather than having to write these same few lines over and over again. I have been looking into the `get()` function, `parse()` function, and `paste0()` function but they does not seem to work properly since they returns the values of a vector/matrix etc. rather than referring directly to the vector/matrix name, so I don't think I can do the thing I want to do (such as adding a column to a matrix) by using these type of functions (at least as far as I know).

Is there a better way to perform this task/shorten my code rather than writing the same code over and over again?

Comment: `AAA111`, etc., must actually be data.frames, otherwise how are you using the `$` operator to assign/access columns?

Comment: The `AAA111` object is a type of matrix/`xts` object, and new columns can be added to `xts` objects by using the `$` operator  (sorry, I should have mentioned it earlier, I'll edit my topic now to include it)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a way to assign different variables to the matrix in each iteration of your process. What I would do is to put everything in a list and then work with the list items.

Take a look:

```
mat_list <- list()

for(i in seq(111, 333, 111)){
  mat <- Matrixsubset[Matrixsubset[,"Buyer.ID"]==as.character(i) | Matrixsubset[,"Seller.ID"]==as.character(i)]
  mat$STOCKS <- stock.function(i, mat)
  mat$STOCKS.Value <- mat$STOCKS * mat$Price

  j <- as.character(i)
  j <- sub(pattern = '([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])', replacement = '\\1')
  j <- as.numeric(j)

  mat_list[[j]] <- mat
}
```

Comment: I see, that's annoying then, if that's the case I may as well leave the original code as it is unchanged :/ Would it be okay if you could go into a bit more details on what's happening in the `j` code lines? i.e. `  j <- as.character(i)`
 ` j <- sub(pattern = '([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])', replacement = '\\1')`
 ` j <- as.numeric(j)` I'm a little unsure what it's needed for. Thanks for the response by the way :)

Comment: Sure! What I did was to turn `i` into a character. So if `i` was, say, `222`, it would be then `"222"`. After that I wanted only the first `2` instead of the whole `222`. So I used `sub` to detect groups of numbers (`[0-9]`) and told it to substitute them for the first group (that's why the `\\1`, it is a backreferencing tool). Then I got `"2"`. Finally I only converted this character into a number with `as.numeric()`.

Comment: If you provide some sample of your data maybe me or someone else may come up with a smaller portion of code that fits your data better.

Comment: Ah I see, but why was it needed for the code though? Since (as far as I can tell) the `j` term is not used elsewhere other than that section. Sorry I'm very new to R so there is a lot I need to learn :( With regard to sample code, I mostly just wanted to know if it was possible to swap the variables so if you're not sure it's possible then I understand (I'm also a little unsure how to post sample code here without it getting too cluttered...)

Comment: No problem, man! Nice that you noticed it, I should have replaced the last `i` for a `j` in the last line of the `for` loop! I edited the answer.

Comment: What about using `get()` and `assign()`? You can use text manipulation fairly easily in this case

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, can you show me an example of how to use it for my case? I've tried using the `get()` function but haven't had any luck with it, but I don't think I've tried using it with `assign()` yet. Can you show me how they can be combined?